# Bootstrap positioning elements

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a section with 6 `<div>` elements.
In medium size device, there are 3 `<div>` elements in a row (there are 2 rows).
In small size device, the last `<div>` element of first row and the first `<div>` element of second row make a new row (there are 3 rows now).
How can I implement that with Bootstrap?

Answer (score 2):

The below code will help you to solve your problem.

```css
.row {
margin: 0 -15px;
}
.col-md-4 {
height: 100px;
padding: 15px;
border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6"></div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6"></div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6"></div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6"></div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6"></div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: good job! It's done. Could you explain how this code snippet funtions? So that I and others can understand more clearly. Tks